# Keynote and presenter note fonts

Tags: keynote

Is there a way to tell Keynote to change the font for all the presenter notes in this file to a specific font? I find that sometimes it screws up the fonts for the notes (not the body) of a bunch of the slides, and it is tedious to change them one-by-one.

Comment: Which version of Keynote?

Comment: I have the same need for Keynote '09.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can edit the XML if you're really stuck:
  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2626026?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Highly recommended making a  backup. Quote from linked page: «Right click your presentation and select +Show Package Content+, you will see a file titled index.apxl.gz. Double click this to unzip giving you a new file index.apxl. Trash the index.apxl.gz and open index.apxl in text edit. Then search for slideNote. Change the part with <sf:fontName><sf:string sfa:string="Font-Name-of-your-font"/></sf:fontName><sf:fontColor><sf:color xsi:type="sfa:calibrated-rgb-color-type" sfa:r="0" sfa:g="0" sfa:b="0" sfa:a="1"/></sf:fontColor><sf:fontSize><sf:number sfa:number=“18” sfa:type="f"/></sf:fontSize>

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where the presenter notes would change size radically for no apparent, making them unreadable.
After checking on a lot of the boards, including Apple's, I tripped across an idea by someone (don't remember who now). I tried it and it worked great.
Quit Keynote, launch Disk Utility, select your hard drive from the list on the left and then select:
**Repair Disk Permissions!**
Quit DU, relaunch Keynote and your presenter notes will (hopefully) fine.
Good luck!